# IE 10 Windows Phone Responsive Redirect Loop

Tags: windows-phone-8, responsive-design, internet-explorer-10

I have used Twitter Bootstrap to make responsive my web stie and on my phone Lumia 920 it's not working. I found a solution in JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    if ("-ms-user-select" in document.documentElement.style && navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
        var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
        msViewportStyle.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}")
        );
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
    }
})();
```

But I have redirect loop on my PC (this script should be run only in IE 10 mobile). The problem is in line:

```
document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}")
```

Because if I comment this line everything works fine but... responsive on IE mobile.
I added in my CSS:

```
@-ms-viewport{
    width: device-width;
}
```